# Error trying to parse settings

Tags: sublimetext2

Here is the exact error I get as I open the program:

`Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings:1:13677`

Comment: You gave the contents of `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`, not `Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings`. Check that file instead (`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings - Default`)

Comment: Just checked the file and there are exactly 13,676 chars.  Not sure what to check.  I could not post all of the code here.  Would specific sections help?

Comment: This is probably a very easy fix, i.e. a missing comma, or bad character in the file.  Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and add the link to your original post.

Comment: Thanks AGS.  I added the gist link to the original question.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the comments and use a service like http://zaach.github.io/jsonlint/ to validate the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings. Check that file instead (Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings - Default

```
{
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "fade_fold_buttons": false,
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 12,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1
}
```